# Detecting browser shutdown in PHP

Tags: php

I know I can use connection_aborted() to explicitly check if the browser closed but then I have to check at discrete points and the browser may close in between my checks.

Is there an exception or something I can catch (I couldn't find one).  I have some processes that may run long and if someone shuts down the browser, and thus aborts the process, I just want to log that such a thing happened.

Comment: This is not possible. With `window.onunload` you could have the browser send an AJAX notice that the window's being closed, but this would be a completely separate request. Other than connection_aborted() and window.unload, you cannot do anything to trap the browser's close events.

Comment: I thought about ignore-user-abort but I really don't need the process to continue if the user has abandoned the page.  I just want to log that the process aborted.

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell if the browser shut down, as HTTP is a stateless protocol. Checking if the connection terminated tells you (usually) if the user lost connection or aborted during page loading. You can only check for closing the browser client-side using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

No. The browser does not have to tell the server that it is about to close a connection. You can try to simulate it with JavaScript pings, but even that is more than error-prone.

Comment: Somehow the web server knows to abort the script. I guess I just want to catch that, and know that the process started but did not complete, even if it's caused by some other issue than the browser closing.